# MySQL: SUM() feature not working

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am trying to sum a column I created by multiplying two other columns and it doesn't seem to be working. I get an error every time I attempt to put in `SUM(PriceTimesQuantity)`

Any and all help would be great!

Here is my query:

```
select 
  OrderedProduct.orderId, 
  CustOrder.customerId, 
  CustOrder.orderDate, 
  OrderedProduct.paidPrice * OrderedProduct.qtyOrdered as PriceTimesQuantity
from OrderedProduct
join CustOrder
  on CustOrder.orderId=OrderedProduct.orderId
where orderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
group by orderDate
```

Comment: What's the error that you get?  What's the full query that you are trying to execute when you are using `SUM(PriceTimesQuantity)`?

Comment: Also note that `SUM()` is defined by the `GROUP BY` statement, therefore if you are grouping by `orderDate`, some values in the query like `CustOrder.customerId` won't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only include columns in the `select` that are either in the `group by` or that are in aggregation functions.  Hence, no columns such as `orderId`.

This is probably closer to what you are trying to do:

```
select co.orderDate, 
       sum(op.paidPrice * op.qtyOrdered) as PriceTimesQuantity
from OrderedProduct op join
     CustOrder co
     on co.orderId = op.orderId
where co.orderDate between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
group by co.orderDate;
```

Your specific error is that you cannot reference an alias defined in the same `select` clause.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. My professor wants to see those columns when I submit my work and that's why I have to include the nonsense ones such as orderId in the select statement. Is there a work around? I also tried the query you listed above and ran into a bunch of errors... :(